# problem about an expression "abêtissez-votis"

Tags: expressions

> This weakling transforms himself, in the name of a know-nothing utopia, into a gravedigger of the intellect; convinced of doing something useful, he prostitutes Pascal’s old “abêtissez-votis,” the Solitary’s tragic device.

Quote from Cioran's "The temptation to exist", translated from French to English by richard howard, my problem is whats the expression "abêtissez-votis", google didnt have a good answer.

Comment: Might be an OCR issue: *abêtissez-vous*?

Answer (score 4):

*Abêtissez-votis* is meaningless in French (or as a mixture of French and Latin).

The explanation is the text you read was improperly transcribed because of an OCR or similar issue. The letter ***u*** is sometimes confused with the sequence of letters ***ti***.

The text then reads ***abêtissez-vous*** which means something like "make yourself dumber", a famous quote from Pascal.